# Mongo aggregate $slice to object instead of array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, slice

I have upgraded Mongo to 3.2 and am delighted that aggregating using $slice works. However, my problem is that I want to assign the value to an object not an array. I cannot find how to do this.

My script applied:

```javascript
db.std_sourceBusinessData.aggregate(
  { $match : {objectType: "Account Balances"}},
  { $project: {_id: 1,entity_id: 1,accountBalances: 1}},
  { $unwind: "$accountBalances" },
  { $match: {"accountBalances": "Sales"}},
  {$project: {
      _id :1, 
      "Value" : {$slice: ["$accountBalances",1,1]},
      "key" : {$literal: "sales"},
      "company": "$entity_id"
  }}
)
```

Comes back with:

```javascript
{
"_id" : ObjectId("566f3da3d58419e8b0fc76c7"),
"Value" : [ 
    "5428.64"
],
"key" : "sales"
}
```

Notice that Value is an array. What I want is:

```javascript
{
"_id" : ObjectId("566f3da3d58419e8b0fc76c7"),
"Value" : "5428.64",
"key" : "sales"
}
```

Thanks, Matt

Comment: add an unwind on Value to aggregation - {$unwind: '$Value'}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt) instead of `$slice` to directly get a single array element.

Modify your final `$project` stage to be:

```js
{$project: {
    _id: 1, 
    "Value": {$arrayElemAt: ["$accountBalances", 1]}, 
    "key": {$literal: "sales"},
    "company": "$entity_id"
}}
```

Comment: That is great Johnny, awesome. That works, one small problem I have just noticed, the "company": "$entity_id" isn't showing. It is in the origin document, is there something I'm missing in here to retrieve values from the origin document directly? Thanks

Comment: You're including `entity_id` in your initial `$project` so that should work fine. Comment out the later pipeline stages and see where it's getting lost. If you're still stuck, post a new question as it's unrelated to this one.

Comment: cool, thanks, I worked out that the first one has ID instead of id, cases sensitivity issue, thanks, Matt